# SQL: How to convert values to lower case and append an s?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'd like to do this but I know this isn't the right syntax:

```
INSERT INTO
               TBL1 SELECT 
               Col1.ToLower + 's'
FROM
               TBL2
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 SELECT LOWER(Col1) + 's'
FROM TBL2
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 SELECT LOWER(Col1) + 's'
FROM TBL2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO TBL1 
SELECT Lower(Col1) + 's'
FROM TBL2
```